# String Pattern Manipulation in R

Tags: r

I am trying to find host and visitor names from a bunch of texts in R.

Sample Text -

```
dat = data.frame(Series = c('England in Australia ODI Match',
'Prudential Trophy (Australia in England)',
'Pakistan in New Zealand ODI Match',
'Prudential Trophy (New Zealand in England)',
'Prudential Trophy (West Indies in England)',
'Australia in New Zealand ODI Series',
'Texaco Trophy (Australia in England)'))
```

I want two new columns to be created.The desired output looks like below -

```
Visitor     Host
England     Australia
Australia   England
Pakistan    New Zealand
New Zealand England
West Indies England
Australia   New Zealand
```

I am trying the following function but it's incomplete.

```
dat$Host = sub(" in.*", "", dat$Series)
```

Comment: If this is related to cricket, you can create  a vector of countries that play the sport. `v1 <- c('England', 'Australia', 'Pakistan', 'New Zealand', 'West Indies'); library(stringr);do.call(rbind, str_extract_all(dat$Series, paste(v1, collapse='|')))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something that does what you want:

```
re = regexpr("((New |West )?\\w+) in ((New |West )?\\w+)", dat$Series)
rm = regmatches(dat$Series, re)
d = do.call(rbind,strsplit(rm, " in "))
colnames(d) = c("Visitor","Host")
```

Output:

```
     Visitor       Host         
[1,] "England"     "Australia"  
[2,] "Australia"   "England"    
[3,] "Pakistan"    "New Zealand"
[4,] "New Zealand" "England"    
[5,] "West Indies" "England"    
[6,] "Australia"   "New Zealand"
[7,] "Australia"   "England"
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. What's "New West" in regexpr function?

Comment: to capture 2 word names like New Zealand or West Indies

Comment: I need your help. Is there a way i can use the following cases along with the cases posted in original question?

x= c("Prudential World Cup (in England)",
"John Player Gold Leaf Trophy (Asia Cup) (Bangladesh, Pakistan, Sri Lanka in Sri Lanka)",
"Morocco Cup (Pakistan, South Africa, Sri Lanka)",
"ICC World Cricket League Championship")

I want NA to return against these cases. Thanks in advance!